# Appending Strings to lpCmdLine WinMain

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Trying to create a loader for an executable, it fails to execute when the length of string supplied in the Parameters is more than some length. But the Parameters are completely read from the initialization file. It also crashes when the Parameters=Null.

```
typedef int (__cdecl *ExecMain_t)(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
HMODULE Loader = LoadLibraryExA(".\\library.dll", NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);

char* Parameters;
CIniFile iniReader(".\\Configure.ini");
Parameters = iniReader.IniReadValue("App", "Parameters");

char xCommand[MAX_PATH] = {0};
_snprintf_s(xCommand, _TRUNCATE, "-verify "); //parameter from exe
strcat_s(xCommand, _TRUNCATE, Parameters);
strcpy_s(lpCmdLine, _TRUNCATE, xCommand);

delete[] Parameters;
Parameters = NULL;

ExecMain_t procExecMain = (ExecMain_t)GetProcAddress(Loader,"ExecMain");
procExecMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);

return 1;
}
```

Crash description:

Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: exec.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    530df50a
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.2.9200.16384

EDIT: Trying to figure out why it crashes when the Parameter string length is increases.

Even crashes if I pass more characters along with "-verify " (passing parameter from exe)

EDIT2: Modified the code by replacing MAX_PATH by _TRUNCATE. Seems to work for some characters in the parameters but when exceeded, crashes.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). Nothing in your current code snippet fully explains the error you are encountering.

Comment: `strcpy`ing into `WinMain`'s `lpCmdLine` sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: any workarounds? Since I've mentioned, it works for smaller strings and breaks for larger or No strings (Null)

Comment: Just drop `strcpy_s` call, and pass `xCommand` directly to `procExecMain`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Parameters are read but seems to be ignored by the executable(even "-verify "). I tried converting char* to char(strncpy) but no luck.

PS: lpCmdLine is LPSTR.

Comment: Well then, debug the executable, figure out why it's ignoring parameters being passed to it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but it doesn't ignore if it were a LPSTR

Comment: `LPSTR` is merely a typedef for `char*`, there's no black magic there. The problem must be in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik please look at edit2

Comment: `_TRUNCATE` is not a valid value for the second parameter of `strcat_s` or `strcpy_s`. You are effectively claiming that the receiving buffer is 0xFFFFFFFF bytes large.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik hmm, I don't kinda get it. command line parameters are passed as it is, but parameters from inside the exe have limited character issue.

Comment: Are you trying to build a command line longer than `MAX_PATH` characters in a buffer that's only `MAX_PATH` character large? If so, why are you surprised that it doesn't work?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just figured out that I was trying to append to lpCmdLine which is LPSTR. Which I guess is illegal, but are there any ways so I can pass my arguments from the executable to the Launcher?

Answer (score 0):

Here are several problems:

```
char xCommand[MAX_PATH] = {0};
_snprintf_s(xCommand, _TRUNCATE, "-verify "); //parameter from exe
strcat_s(xCommand, _TRUNCATE, Parameters);
strcpy_s(lpCmdLine, _TRUNCATE, xCommand);
```

I think you should use `strcpy_s` instead of `_snprintf_s`, after all I don't see you printing any format in `xCommand`.

Then, the second parameter, `_TRUNCATE` should actually be `MAX_PATH` since the second parameter of this functions is the number of elements of the destination buffer.

But most important, the third line is completely wrong, because you're trying to write into the input buffer `lpCmdLine` and that will overwrite the memory beyond the buffer bounds. What you need is to copy the content of the original buffer into your new command buffer. Something like this (notice I wrote this code in the browser so it may contain errors):

```
char xCommand[MAX_PATH] = {0};
strcpy_s(xCommand, MAX_PATH, lpCmdLine); // copy the original command line
strcat_s(xCommand, MAX_PATH, " -verify "); // append
strcat_s(xCommand, MAX_PATH, Parameters); // append
```

and then pass this buffer to your `ExecMain` function:

```
procExecMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, xCommand, nCmdShow);
```

Comment: I did something similar to your solution but it seems xCommand is simply ignored. lpCmdLine is only thing passed to Loader.